# Need some help to refactor ternary

Tags: ternary

i did this ternary operator and this works but i know it could be better. If anyone can help me to refactor this code, that will be great

```
disabled={ mainCurrency.code
              ? currency.code
                 ? currency.code === mainCurrency.code
                   ? true
                   : false
                 : true
               : true
          }
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Unclear what programming language are you using. Please update tags

Comment: So if mainCurrency is not set or currency is not set or mainCurrency is equal to currency than it is true.

Comment: Looks like to be Javascript, add the JavaScript tag and whatever template library you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if mainCurrency is not set or currency is not set or mainCurrency is equal to currency than it is true. Writing it out would be

```
!mainCurrency.code || !currency.code || currency.code === mainCurrency.code
```